# ObjectiveC - Crash while loading tableView Cells

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have written this method in objectiveC (for iOS but that immaterial). My app crashes when calling this method. I am writing all this in my `.m` file. Am not able to figure out the reason for the crash...

```
-(UITableViewCell *)myCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
               forRowIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //customize the cell.
    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellId = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell   = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellId];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ResultsOne" owner:self options:nil];
        cell         = self.resultsOne;
    }
    cell = [self myCell:cell:indexPath]; //code crashes here
    return cell;
}
```

**What am i doing wrong ?**

Comment: Can you provide us with any error text from the debugger/console?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be `cell = [self myCell:cell forRowIndex:indexPath];` 

Maybe I'm wrong, though

Comment: @krypton, here goes - `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FLOViewController myCell::]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x114c50'`
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: As a side note, you're using pretty outdated methods for loading the cell. Take a look at `UITableView.register(UINib:,forCellReuseIdentifier:)` and `UITableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:,for:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write the method call like this:

`cell = [self myCell:cell forRowIndex:indexPath];`

Comment: All aargs that are passed on objectiveC are pointers? or are they copied (i.e. passed by value)?

Comment: @Srikar Objective-C args don't _have_ to be pointers. You could pass an int as an argument. But in this case, the argument is an object. Objects in Objective-C are _always_ pointers, since they can't be statically allocated.

Answer (score 0):

please check the signature of the method "myCell:"  .
as @Robert Fratto  pointed out it might be some thing else.
Document says:

**`[myRectangle setOrigin:30.0 :50.0]; // This is a bad example of multiple arguments

Since the colons are part of the method name, the method is named setOrigin::. It has two colons as it takes two arguments. This particular method does not interleave the method name with the arguments and, thus, the second argument is effectively unlabeled and it is difficult to determine the kind or purpose of the method’s arguments.`**

Answer (score 0):

Because you are missing method signature while calling. Below is the correction.

Your Call:

```
cell = [self myCell:cell:indexPath]; //code crashing here...!
```

Actual Call :

```
cell = [self myCell:cell forRowIndex:indexPath]; // It'll work for sure as we following the correct method signature from your above code.
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to write the method call like this:

```
if(cell == nil)   
{
       cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ResultsOne"owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];          
}
```

Than after, you call:

`cell = [self myCell:cell forRowIndex:indexPath];`